# Convex conjugate: Lipschitz continuity of the argmax function

Tags: optimization, continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $s,\delta\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a compact convex set, $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable strictly convex function on $S$ and $$s\left(\delta\right)=\arg\max_{s\in S}s\cdot\delta-f\left(s\right).$$
Notice that this is related to the definition of convex conjugate of $f$:
 $$f^*\left(\delta\right)\equiv\max_{s\in S}s\cdot\delta-f\left(s\right).$$
Being $f$ strictly convex, $s\left(\cdot\right)$ is single valued, and it is continuous by the maximum theorem. My question: is $s\left(\cdot\right)$ Lipschitz continuous? If not, which additional conditions do I need to get Lipschitz continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (global) Lipschitz continuity should be equivalent to $f$ being strongly convex. In order to find a counterexample, you should try some $f$ which is not strongly convex.